# why do astronauts in the ISS still use wired microphones?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, communication, radio-communication

While I watched the DM-1 hatch opening, I noticed that astronauts use the wired microphone to talk to Huston.
It was particularly strange seeing that even because during hatch opening, they were required to wear rebreathers and that meant quite a workaround to speak to ground control.

that can be seen in this video around 1:46 mark
[DM-1 opening](https://youtu.be/NANBfNI5tR4?t=109)

So, why not use a [laryngophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throat_microphone)? they are commonly used in the military, they are military hardened and definitely much more comfortable. also, they are wireless and since they don't require access to the mouth they can be weared with gas masks without problems.

Also, they could enable an astronaut to talk while having both hands on an experiment.

So, why do they still do "wired"?

Comment: Can't answer but I can speculate - reliability.  No need to recharge it, can't run out of battery, not susceptible to noise/signal degradation.

Comment: @Baldrickk I agree with your speculation. NASA really doesn't like bringing new batteries on to the ISS, particularly because lithium based ones can be so explosive. In the past, all mobile electronics on the ISS were adapted to accept rechargable AA batteries to minimize risk.

Comment: Note that they do (or did) use wireless microphones. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/why-do-iss-astronauts-use-lower-quality-microphones-for-official-radio-communica?rq=1

Comment: So, it seems that there is not a problem with radiofrequency or other E/M noises. Battery seems really the only explanation.

Comment: Wired throat microphones are also available and would solve the rebreather problem.

Comment: Also, a wired microphone is a microphone that's more likely to be where you left it when you take it off.